# ¿Como hago para que me traiga un dato especifico de la BD y no el primero que encuentre?

Tags: php, mysql

actualmente estoy haciendo una consulta con php para que me traiga un dato especifico del usuario que se esta usando, tengo lo siguiente, pero me trae el primer dato que encuentra de dicha columna (empresa), y no el relacionado con el usuario logueado en el momento.

```
<?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM wck_usuarios"; 
    $ejecutar = mysql_query($consulta, $link); 
    $i = 0; 
    while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($ejecutar))
    { 
        $id = $fila['id']; 
        $empresa = $fila['empresa']; 
        $i++; 
        ?>
            <input class="refor" type="text" name="empresa" readonly="" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($empresa); ?>"> 

        <?php 
    } 
    mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: este es el codigo que estoy usando.

Comment: Es obvio que va a traer siempre el primero pues no estas restringiendo en ningun momento por el usuario.

Comment: Deberias de utilizar sentencias preparadas tal y como lo recomienda PHP en su documentación. http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar consultas con condiciones - en este caso tú quieres traer datos de un usuario específico -, debes especificar dicha condición con *Where*:

```
SELECT * FROM wck_usuarios WHERE usuario = 'usuario requerido'
```